# Why do door knobs still exist?

Tags: ergonomics, household

As far as I know, in US, grip-and-turn style door knobs are still the most popular, as opposed to lever-style handles, which dominate in the rest of the world.

Is there some UX advantage to door knobs that I am not aware of, which is the reason for keeping them around?

Edit:

To clarify the difference, this is the grip-and-turn door knob:

[image: door knob]

And this is lever-handle style:

[image: door lever]

Comment: Do you have any source concerning the "dominate in the rest of the world" part? I'm pretty used to "grip-and-turn" door knobs in France too.

Comment: They make for excellent plot devices in low budget horror films since it is hard to open them with your hands covered in blood

Comment: @ArlaudPierre, Not, sorry. Just my subjective impression. I'd be very keen to see any statistics on the subject too.

Comment: Same here@statistic, I am surprised to hear grip-and-turn door knobs are the norm anywhere to be honest. Only on front doors I have see them from time to time for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: You rarely see any grip-and-turn knobs in germany. And if you do, they even seem to be confused with knobs that you can't turn at all. Those unturnable knobs are quite frequently used on the outside of front doors or doors without a snap/latch lock.

Comment: In the US, grip and turn knobs are used in virtually all _homes_, while lever style are often seen in offices. So we are very familiar with both types.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing how levers have a better UX than knobs. I find that knobs are much easier to use because you can turn then very quickly without having to mount your hand in a specific way on a lever.

Comment: @Keavon: How do you open and close a door with a knob from both sides when you are carrying something with both hands?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, This is largely due to the Americans with Disabilities Act, which recommends against doorknobs in favor of lever handles, and applies to businesses but not to private residences.

Comment: FYI, I had to replace my lever style bedroom door knob with a grip and turn version because the cat figured out how to jump up, pull the lever and bust into the room. He liked to come in mostly at times when the door was closed for a reason.

Comment: Not a UX answer, but a practical one. When installing in some doors, especially those with large lock mechanisms (generally much older ones), it can be difficult to get a door knob screwed firmly enough to the thin wood (or whatever the door is made of) left either side. The larger plate associated with most lever-type handles easily 'bridges' this lock part and allows for screwing into the solid wood either side. Grub screws to hold the door knob to the spindle mitigate this only partially.

Comment: I wanted to mention that I can open a door with lever using my butt only. But I also wonder why in some doorknob cultures, they tend to put the knob in the *center* of the door? Of course that looks more symmetric, but this doubles the force nneded to open and sometimes you cannot even guess beforehand which way the dorr swings ...

Comment: Ever tried to open a door knob with wet hands?

Comment: There is also a compromise: an egg shaped knob that is still mostly round, but is easier to grip for people with lower grip strength. It has the huge advantage of not being easy for cats (or dogs, bears or velociraptors) to operate, and not being as prone to hooking clothing as a handle. (I had a door that ripped my pants clean off me once. I hate handles.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: You can open an inward-opening (from your perspective) door with a lever using your butt only?

Comment: @benPearce: Exactly - or one that is somewhat stuck and thus requires some greater force.

Comment: When it comes to building/construction, it's usually just tradition. If it wasn't for inertia and tradition, we probably wouldn't see doorknobs as much as we do, just like we wouldn't see separate Hot/Cold taps in UK bathrooms (Not to mention cars driving on the left).

Comment: Ever try to hang a tie on one of those levers?

Comment: No-one has questioned the visual appeal of knobs vs doors?  Maybe they just look better!?

Comment: It's all fun and games until the velociraptors learn to open your lever-handle doors.

Comment: I've hurt myself with a handle before. I've also had clothes get stuck on handles before. That's never happened with a knob.

Comment: I have never caught my sleeve on a traditional door handle, however it would seem my sleeve always catches on levers

Comment: What about child-safety? While the eyes of a child are at the same level as the lever, they are in serious danger. There are some very serious accidents where childs are losing one of their eyes from it.

Comment: @styu: Aren't the eyes of a child just as well on the same level as a door knob?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - now I'll have this mental picture dancing in front of my eyes all day. Just *please* don't mention that you do this while humming "The Lion Sleeps Tonight", OK? :-)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - given the size of a typical doorknob vis-a-viz the size of the eye socket of a child, I suspect that the worst that a doorknob would do would be to give the kid a black eye.

Comment: @BobJarvis: I have realized only several days after reading these messages that all the people talking about child safety here are not assuming the child falling "somehow" onto the door handle, but exactly from the direction that the handle points to. That sounds rather unlikely, maybe comparable to the risk of using any doors at all because they could somehow unhinge and crush someone to death. That said, there is a variety of ways to reduce that risk, such as by partially submerging the handle into the door, or by shaping the handle so that it "bends back" toward the door at its end.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - as a former military safety officer, as well as being the father of three girls who currently compete or have in the past competed in sports where injury is not uncommon (gymnastics, soccer), I pay attention to safety hazards in the home, workplace, and world. Honestly, I don't see door knobs or handles as a major risk. If we somehow built a risk-free world which eliminated all risk of injury I don't think many people would want to live there as I suspect it would be a very dull place. Swing sets - GONE! Sports - GONE! Cars - GONE! Thanks, I'll accept a bit of risk... :-)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper imagine a child rushing (small children are always rushing everywhere) into a room with an inward opening door, coming from the side of the hinge, pushing the door open with their body and brushing along the length of the door. The handle is pointing in exactly the right direction and roughly the right distance out from the door to hit them in the eye.

Comment: @jwg: A closed door cannot be pushed open with one's body without pressing the handle/turning the door knob.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper if the door was ajar or partially open.

Comment: @jwg: In that case, the solution is trivial: Close doors properly :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis: *I* was not the one claiming that door handles pose an inacceptable safety risk :)

Comment: I feel the same way about buttons. Zippers are demonstrably superior. Especially on baby clothes!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you still have a problem when a group of kids chase each other into the room. Or should the door be shut between each one?

Comment: @jwg: The rule "no running while inside" used to be quite strictly enforced by my parents. Possibly, that's one of the reasons why.

Comment: My personal opinion is that the knob gives me a better turning experience.

Comment: Related question on Home Improvement: [Any hidden disadvantage to lever-type door latches?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/136784/23731)

Comment: I use doorknobs in my home to keep dogs and cows from taking over.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Door *knobs* are standard in US homes for the same reason that exterior doors open inwards* -- it's "always been done that way". People grow up used to knobs, and specify knobs on new work, and thus this inferior mechanism is perpetuated. For some buildings (not private homes), some building codes now require lever mechanisms so that the handicapped can operate them more easily. In most buildings with high occupancy (schools, commercial space), outward-opening doors with crash bars are required. These codes came after some tragic fires, where people piled up against inward-opening doors.

I don't see lever mechanisms and outward-opening doors becoming common in US homebuilding, unless codes are amended to require them. Considering how much pushback there has been over incandescent lightbulbs, I don't see that happening any time soon. Maybe if there is some sort of "handicap accessible" certification that would make a home easier to sell, that would encourage the change.

* originally in colonial homes, doors that opened inwards could be barricaded from the inside to prevent hostile attackers from breaking down the door. The tradition has continued to this day.

Comment: More on why doors open inward in homes here: http://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/remodeling/question584.htm.

Comment: I'd be curious to see a citation on the last bit about colonial homes. It seems like it would have to do with any hostile person, not just Native Americans, and would go back further than colonial times.

Comment: Looking around for a citation, I saw suggestions that 1) in snowy areas an outward-opening door could trap you inside (and code thus requires inward-opening in some areas), 2) hinges on the outside can have their pins driven out by a burglar, 3) the wind can catch an outward-opening door and damage it. But I do remember being told long ago about being able to barricade an inward-opening door. I will try to find an acceptable citation.

Comment: In the US, lever handles are usually a _recommendation_ by the ADA. Crash bars (when present) are usually a _requirement_ by the OSHA.

Comment: OSHA has nothing to do with schools, theatres, and clubs. That is fire code.

Comment: Our home, in Minnesota USA and built in 1976, was originally equipped with levers (and still is).

Comment: The usefulness of lever knobs seems way overblown to me. They don't help "when your hands are full" except on doors that open inwards. And even then, only if the door does not require a key. Most levers are horizontal, which is mostly ergonomic when pulling, but not so much when pushing. There are advantages for levers if you have limited grip strength, though you're also more likely to be hooked by one. And most levers are not designed for safety or ergonomics but to look good.

Comment: I find levers to be the inferior mechanism for my usages.  As mentioned above, levers are not helpful with hands full and can even be worse because the release points on the current lever sets are all too far down, making it harder to open than with a knob.  Pulling doors closed with levers twists the mounting points (since the point the force is applied to is not centered, unlike knobs where it is), leading to loosening/early failure/breakage.  Levers are great for snagging pockets/bagging clothing and tearing it.

Comment: to be fair, doors that open outwards are harder to break down since the entire frame around the door basically prevents the door from opening inward at all.

Comment: @Wayne: Can you turn a doorknob to open an outwards-opening door with your elbow, while your hands are full? And how many interior doors within your house do you actually ever lock so opening them would need a key? Also, can you elaborate why levers that are between horizontal and 45° turned are not ergonomic for pushing?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Actually, levers *are* helpful with hands full. With hands full, a door with a door knob is impossible to open or close, but that's well possible with a lever, just using one's elbow, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: You cannot close a door that opens "away from you" by "pushing". But, yes, exactly my point about how to open and close doors with levers with the elbow.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Total brain fade on my part, there.

Comment: I always thought that part of the reason why residential home front exterior doors opened inwards was to allow for secondary screen/glass doors. This would be a more "modern" change (as compared to the barricading example), but it would still be awkward otherwise with an outward swinging main door.

Answer (score 164):

Doorknobs provide a [*worse* UX for bears](http://www.economist.com/news/americas/21600988-new-building-rules-will-help-old-folkswho-now-risk-being-eaten-bears-knobless-oblige), which can be a useful feature for humans who want to keep bears out.

> ...elderly and disabled people find it easier to operate doors with handles. But so do bears. In British Columbia, bears have been known to scavenge for food inside cars—whose doors have handles, knob advocates point out. Pitkin County, Colorado, in the United States, has banned door levers on buildings for this very reason. One newspaper columnist in the pro-knob camp has noted that the velociraptors in “Jurassic Park” were able to open doors by their handles.

Comment: ah, the bear factor! Always an important UX metric to consider!

Comment: Also used in all homes in Tokyo, where bears are a rare sight.

Comment: Leading to the spawn-off question "why don't car doors have grip-and-turn style knobs to fend off bears, children and elderly"?

Comment: Actually, a determined bear will just pry open the whole car door. No handles or knobs needed. It's just a poor user experience for the bear, that's all.

Comment: I actually knew a dog that could open doors this way. We had to keep our front door locked so he wouldn't come in an let our dog out.

Comment: Gotta keep those pesky velociraptors out of the house! Seriously, a bear will get in through almost any door or window, if they sense food is inside. I've had them try to climb up a downspout to get to a second floor birdfeeder!

Comment: So basically they're like pill bottles: deliberately make it difficult to open so beings without the necessary understanding of the tool involved can't get in.

Comment: I am seriously confused, this answer is primarily meant as a joke right? Not as a serious answer to the actual question? (the reason I am confused is the number of upvotes)

Comment: @DavidMulder It is a humorous (but not a joke) answer to an odd question. The popularity of this answer has surprised me. At the same time, it is also a serious answer: it may be the only answer here with a citation that contains a definitive reason. As long as some town in Colorado forbids door handles, doorknobs will continue to exist.

Comment: Not just bears, i use door knobs on doors where i don't want our cats to get through, so they can't steal food at night.

Comment: Bears-shmears, I am more worried about the velociraptors.

Comment: Is it the Bear factor, or the Beer factor?

Comment: http://img.pandawhale.com/71510-python-snake-opens-door-gif-Ju-K9nA.gif

Answer (score 68):

They are harder for little hands and jumping pets to open (though turning a lever door handle to the vertical also works for these purposes).

They are also somewhat less likely to have things catch on them (bag straps, stray elbows), especially in confined spaces.

Comment: I thought that difficulty for the kids opening them would be a disadvantage in most cases?

Comment: @MladenJablanović Depends on their age and whether you want them to be able to open the door :)

Comment: I still think those are not big enough (dis)advantages that any side switches to the other; people use them because people around them use them.

Comment: I agree with the "catchy-thing" argument but I reckon the lever-style handles have a better [call-to-action/affordance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance#As_perceived_action_possibilities)

Comment: What @PlasmaHH describes is known as the [network effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect)

Comment: I don't think it is worth adding another answer because this one already alluded to it, but keep in mind the knob also occupies less space in general, so if the handle is considered an eye-sore in general, the knob is the lowest possible profile.  A lever is basically just a knob with a handle attached.

Comment: Is this actually the reason for them existing though, or are you just applying some retrocausality - assuming a reason where one may not exist? Do the suppliers state this is why they make them or is it more *"it's just how we've always made them"*?

Comment: I'm at the exact height so that I also constantly get belt loops stuck in the door handles.

Comment: I just want to say that the whole reason I use knobs is so my dogs can't open doors.  I've had a husky who was keen on opening doors, and my Great Pyrenees does it too.  Both are capable of handling several types of locks as well.  My Pyrenees and lab have even teamed up when attempting to open doors.  There are a lot of breeds of dog that are smart enough to use doors if given the chance, so for owners of medium to large dogs, it's a very real concern.

Comment: @Ryan, I had a friend in high school who's Labrador would open doors with _doorknobs_, so it's not foolproof! :)

Comment: I've seen the two cats of my friends open doors by jumping up and catching the handle - it got that bad that they now have to lock their front door all the time to avoid the cats getting out. So yep bad usability can be an advantage. On the other hand seeing a cat hang on a door handle is entertainment for hours.

Comment: There are also [safety systems](http://www.amazon.com/Mommys-Helper-Door-Safety-Cover/dp/B000MF518O) that make it possible for an adult to open a door, but for children (with smaller/weaker hands) to be unable to do so. Of course, they only work with a round knob.

Comment: I have a cat that can open horizontal door levers, plus I have lost at least two expensive suits to getting one of the pockets caught on a lever handle.  More than enough reason to prefer door knobs in many situations.

Answer (score 48):

Doors are either left-handed or right-handed, depending on which way they open. Doorknobs can be installed on either side of the door.

Handles are normally designed for either the right or left side of the door (i.e. you need a left/right pair for each door, one on this side of the door, the other on the other side of the door). (This appears to be a topic of confusion, and it seems that this confusion is wide-spread.... There happens to be a door-handle company that has run in to this, and [they have put together a detailed description/diagram of the problem....](http://www.houseofantiquehardware.com/s.nl/ctype.KB/it.I/id.3245/KB.70/.f) Unfortunately, [Wikipedia disagrees about door handing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handing) .... i.e. there is lots of confusion. The point remains though, that the handles (often) have a 'handing')

You will likely find that less material is needed for a doorknob as well, so they are cheaper. The handle on a handle provides leverage, which means it takes less weight/force to operate the latch mechanism (and less force to overload the mechanism too), so a Handle's mechanism needs to be stronger to support the same forces a doorknob would be exposed to. Also, just the shape of the lever means there is more metal..... A knob would have much less raw-material than a handle.

If you expand the UX scope to include the sticker-shock when you purchase one, then knobs have a better UX ;-)    (and, also probably a smaller 'carbon footprint', environmental cost....)

Here's [a google-search images for 'door handle'](https://www.google.ca/search?q=door+handle&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=202DU6P3FJCkyATHpYHQCQ&ved=0CEAQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=722).

Note how almost all the handles are specifically shaped.

[image]

Those that are not specifically shaped, often have a base-plate that makes the mounting different for different door-sides.

[image]

Only a few of the handles have a round/ambidextrous handle **and** mounting plate.

[image]

Out of interest, door handles normally have a 'stop' built in to the handle which limits the handle's travel to avoid stressing the actual bolt mechanism in the door (on the other hand, knobs don't have that leverage, so they let the mechanism in the door be the 'stop'). This mechanical stop requires the handle to be securely fastened *to the door*, so handles (with their additional leverage) need a stronger mounting (the mechanical stop *in the handle* also often prevents you from being able to reverse the handle on the mounting plate).

With the ambidextrous mounting plates on some of the handles, you would probably use a stronger door/lock in order to support the leverage on the handle, which transfers the cost to be elsewhere....

Comment: While levers that are attached to their baseplate can't be swapped, if you can swap the interior and exterior handles, then the lever becomes usable in either direction.  Try this simple thing to see how it works.  Put out your pinkies towards each other and use your thumbs as the levers.  Touch your pinkies and point your hands one way, now switch which hand is closest to you and you can see that the lever now points in the opposite direction and could fit a door opening in the other direction.

Comment: Here's a video that shows it too. http://www.kwikset.com/Customer-Support/Product-FAQs/faq/50160000000HhaDAAS.aspx

Comment: @AJHenderson - your comments are accurate in the sense that it is possible to reverse the handles *for some products*, and, I imagine, at significant additional expense. The point I am making is that doorknobs are cheaper because you don't even have to consider these problems from design, through manufacturing, through installation, etc. you don't need to even think about what way a door opens when you make a purchasing decision, and installation is faster/easier with a knob. All about the $$$$

Comment: I don't remember last time using door knobs, could they operate turning both ways (meaning, could I open the door turning the knob either way)? If not, they are not ambidextrous. Also, most of the door handles I used can be mounted either side of the door.

Comment: @MladenJablanović - the knob (when not mounted to the door) can just spin, and spin, and spin, in any direction. It is the mechanism inside the door that only turns one way (and not all mechanisms are one-way only...).

Comment: Whether the lever handle is "leftie friendly" or not is nothing to do with the lever itself. The direction that the lever points in is *entirely dependent* on how the door opens (i.e. which side the hinges happen to be).

Comment: @Franchesca - never mentioned 'leftie-friendly' at all, but, door-sets are described as left or right handed based on the way they are mounted, and the way the door opens ....

Comment: @rolfl yes, but all this talk about ambedexterousness is confusing the issue. Just clarifying that it is the door mounting that creates the "handedness" of the door, and it is completely unrelated to the design of the handle. Doors with knob handles that open "right handedly" are not better for lefties than doors with levers. In fact I would say it is the other way around. Pushing the lever handle down with your left hand on a right handed opening door is way easier than turning a knob handle on a right handed door. Try it and see for yourself :)

Comment: Is you answer also essentially "knobs are cheaper"? If so, you should up-vote my answer. As for why they are cheaper, you bring up good points, but I don't think the extra material or the additional stop would cause such a difference in price.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky -  Your answer is that competition has driven prices down, making knobs more affordable. My answer is that knobs are inherently simpler due to physics, use less material, and cost less to manufacture. I disagree with your answer even if it arrives at the same conclusion (that knobs are cheaper).

Comment: @rolfl Actually, my answer was "knobs are cheaper." The rest was supposition. To settle the matter, we could compare the weight and parts count of knob vs handle *assemblies* and their average selling prices. I expect the difference in price to be significantly greater than the difference in weight or part count.

Comment: I don't quite see the issue about the "specifically shaped" levers that cannot be detached from their baseplate. Normally, in particular for interior doors between rooms, the same type of levers is used on both sides of the door. Consequently, you don't buy single levers, but a *pair* of (mirrored) levers. That way, it doesn't even matter on which "side" of the door the levers will be placed; the pair will always fit.

Comment: @BraddSzonye, Most interior doors (in the US, at least) are going to either have no lock, or have a privacy lock (the push button you speak of). If you're locking the bathroom door, it's not to keep malevolent intruders out, it's to stop someone from walking in on you at the wrong time. Obviously, a homeowner can go to a hardware store and change what types of locks are throughout the house, but interior key locks on rooms are uncommon. (And inconvenient, as you'd have to carry your keys everywhere if you intend to utilize them!)

Comment: @Brian It's not about security, it's about the fact that a left-handed locking handle won't fit on a right-handed door. Knobs don't generally have that problem. It doesn't even matter whether there's a keyhole, just that the handles are different.

Comment: @BrianS: Why do you have to carry any keys around? In almost all the houses I've known, all doors simply have a keyhole on both sides, and in the very few rooms that are ever going to be locked (normally, if at all, just the bathroom), the key is simply readily in that keyhole on the desired side of the door.

Comment: There is no 'significant additional expense' in changing which side of the door a pair of handles are fitted to. You simply take the door handles out of the packet in a different order. The link you quote is about hinges.

Answer (score 34):

Since you mentioned the US, I feel it's important to bring up the Americans with Disabilities Act (ADA). Among many other things, the ADA has this to say on the subject:

> **Advisory 404.2.7 Door and Gate Hardware.** Door hardware that can be operated with a 
>   closed fist or a loose grip accommodates the greatest range of users. Hardware that 
>   requires simultaneous hand and finger movements require greater dexterity and 
>   coordination, and is not recommended.

In other words, the ADA recommends *against* door knobs, but does not *require* lever handles.

Do note that the ADA does not apply to all doors in the country (private residences which are not also used for business purposes do not need to adhere to the ADA, for example), and the ADA only applies to things built (or modified) after the ADA went into effect (July 1992), so an old building that hasn't been updated wouldn't necessarily be subject to the ADA standards.

Comment: doors that are secured with rfid tags and automagically open meet these criteria also.

Comment: … which raises the question, Why _are_ doorknobs still being produced?

Answer (score 24):

I'm from the UK, live in Spain, and I certainly noticed a lot more grip and turn knobs when I was in the USA. One advantage is that they often have a lock built in (either a key lock for a front door, or a push button for a bathroom.)

This makes the appearance neater and the installation easier than the typical European handle, which must have a separate lock. The USA is a country of low material costs and high labour costs, so the convenience of installation may be relevant.

Other advantages: things don't get caught on them as readily (I've torn a shirt or two in my time.) And certainly they're a lot less likely to injure you should you ever fall on one or scrape against it. This is definitely an advantage for boisterous children who may have their heads at doorknob height. The point about being harder for children to open can be either good or bad.

EDIT: There are other ways to protect children from door handles. Thanks to @Mew for the link:  japantoday.com/images/size/x/2012/05/handles.jpg

[image]

Comment: While your explanations sounds reasonable, less of a chance for things getting "caught" is, at the same time, a disadvantage: How do you open and close a door with a doorknob when you are carrying something in both hands (say, a filled glass and a plate with food)? For lever style grips, both opening and closing is still easily possible with one's elbow.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper true, but the question asks for advantages of round doorknobs, not disadvantages. Also, I'm the only one whose given a plausible  explanation why there are more round doorknobs in the USA than other parts of the world.

Comment: Upon reading your answer, it just sounded a bit one-sided, but you're right about the question asking only about advantages. As for your explanation on that being specific to the USA, though, I am not convinced about that. "Low material costs and high labour costs" could be said about various European countries just as well. For example, I hear in the USA, there are even employees packing stuff into bags at supermarkets, which is something completely unknown in most European countries exactly because the labour cost is way too high for such tasks.

Comment: I don't buy the "cheaper to install" part. Both styles IMO take the same amount of work to install. Both styles require doors with prepared slots for the lock and lever (or knob). Then all you have to do is mount the lock and lever.

Comment: Note: there exist lever handles with a "knob" lock; you're not limited to having a separate locking mechanism. Most of the ones I've _personally_ seen were privacy locks rather than security locks, but merely having a lever handle does not preclude the incorporation of a lock.

Comment: @MladenJablanović not so. *For a round doorknob with built in lock:* 1.Get a standard solid door. 2.Drill a large hole for the knob mechanism. 3. Drill a small hole for the tang that protrudes into the doorframe (the part that withdraws when you turn the knob. 4.install the mechanism through the knob hole. 5. drill some screwholes to fix the covers and install the screws. *For a door handle with separate lock:* drill a large hole for the handle mechanism and a smaller one for the keyhole. Now hack an enormous rectangular hole in the edge of the door to install the mechanism! Finish as before.

Comment: @steveverrill, A lever handle does not require a separate locking mechanism due to being a lever handle (and therefore would not necessarily need the second hole for the lock). Additionally, many knobs are installed along with a dead bolt, even if the knob being used has a knoblock (thus requiring a second hole despite being a knob).

Comment: See this: http://www.japantoday.com/images/size/x/2012/05/handles.jpg

Comment: @steveverrill: You're right. Over here, when you buy a door, they already come prepared, with a drilled slot for the mechanism (there are 2-3 standard sizes for them). We're might be onto something here - standardization, rather than the difficulty of installing.

Comment: Just a comment on catching clothing etc. on a lever. I once encountered a spherical metal doorknob where the nickel/chrome plating was faulty and had detached. If someone had grabbed it and twisted, they would have had a very nasty gash to their hand. That's probably so rare an event that it would not be considered an advantage of lever over knob (less sliding motion on a lever, more direct pressure).

Comment: @Mew Sorry I took two days to open your link. That image is so good it has to go in the answer!

Answer (score 19):

This is a classic case where **the decision-makers are not the users**.

Doorknobs tend to be installed by home builders, whose goals are minimizing cost and minimizing cost and also minimizing cost. Round door knobs are cheap, plentiful, and understood to be an acceptable solution. For internal doors, this makes them the norm.

Lever-style doorknobs are much more expensive, and can be trickier to be install. It doesn't matter if a doorknob is slightly out of level, but it's very obvious with a handle-style.

There is also a **huge installed base** out there--billions of doors which are set up for round doorknobs. Retrofitting a lever-style door opener may require replacing the door and/or modifying the striker plate side. Inertia and cost wins.

In industrial installs and new construction, you frequently see lever-style doors. As well as some ergonomic benefits, they have the advantage of generally being more durable. A business is responsible for maintenance of its property in a way that a home builder is not.

Comment: Can you just clarify "trickier to install", I don't get that part. Out of level in which way? Thanks!

Comment: When installing a knob, it can be "twisted" with respect to level and you won't notice--the only sign is that the screw holes (mostly hidden by the knob) may not be perfectly aligned. With a handle, the entire handle will be tilted to the left or right. A professional installer will have a jig that makes this easier...which costs money and takes extra training.

Comment: Interesting you say they're more common on internal doors. Here in Ireland, I don't think I've *ever* seen them on internal doors.

Comment: We have doorknobs because we bought our condo before it was built and the builder asked if we wanted knobs or levers. So we got knobs cause we hate stuff catching on the levers, which we had at our previous apartment.

Comment: @TRiG Do you see them on external doors, or do you not see them at all?

Comment: On external, @cpast, it depends. Quite often there's a knob which doesn't turn on the outside, used only to pull the door closed.

Comment: @TRiG I'm Irish and I've noticed that older houses in Ireland usually have knobs instead of levers. I have a few friends who live in old Victorian houses in Bray, Wicklow, and they all have round doorknobs. My house is much newer than theirs and we have levers. I only live a short distance from them too.

Comment: IIRC, Ireland had a huge amount of new construction in the 90s. Maybe you're seeing the newer install base?

Comment: Supporting the price factor: on homedepot.com right now, plain Jane door *knobs* are $8 to $20; levers are pretty consistently $20 for basic models.

Answer (score 8):

Vancouver has banned doorknobs through its building code. 
The motive is for greater accessibility. And I can think of several reasons why levers offer a lot more affordance. Elbows, forearms, feet, items gripped in a hand, butts can all be used to open doors with handle knobs... but that is or will be discussed. I recommend this fascinating article on the topic.

**[Vancouver’s ban on the humble doorknob likely to be a trendsetter](http://www.vancouversun.com/story.html?id=9173543)**

Comment: Building codes give uniformity, but do not necessarily give the best user experience. For years in the UK, everyone understood that all taps were lefty-loosey, righty-tighty. Then the European union decreed that hot taps should be the reverse: i.e. turn clockwise to open. The result is a lot of confusion (people often don't look at the colour of a tap) and a lot of hot taps wrenched off their respective sinks. No wonder every modern bathroom in continental Europe now has a mixer tap with a single handle for both hot and cold (lift for on, right/left for temperature.)

Comment: Argh that's horrible. :(

Comment: @steveverrill: Are you sure that the mixer tap has become widespread in response to said regulation? I'd have thought that was simply because mixer taps are superior in that they allow for a direct control of both water pressure and temperatures independently of each other.

Comment: This answers the opposite question, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm not saying it is the only reason for the popularity of the single-handle mixer, but it has certainly accelerated the trend. User Exp with hot taps is now awful. If you're rinsing your hands after using the toilet all you care about is having "some water", you don`t care much about temperature. Assuming you have correctly identified that you are dealing with a hot tap you have to guess which way to turn it by judging its age. Interestingly one of the other answers here identifies a building code requiring the exact opposite of this one. http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/57968/46297

Comment: @steveverrill [citation needed]. I've never noticed any such issue with bathroom taps and I can't find anything online. It's hard to believe that the EU could legislate about which direction bathroom taps should turn without the *Daily Mail* screaming about it, for example. This sounds a lot like a euromyth.

Comment: I could not find any EU legislation on this either, but an explanation which is a lot more plausible: http://www.baddesigns.com/faucet2.html

Basically that you can get the same faucet with either screw-taps or lever-taps, and the lever-taps require opposite directions.

Answer (score 6):

They seem to be the cheapest in the stores. Both in the US and when I was in Ukraine. So the question becomes, why are they the cheapest?

My *hunch* is it's a result of round knobs all looking essentially the same, which caused more competition among manufacturers, which lowered their price, so they became more popular, more factories invested in the tooling to make them, and they've been cheaply cranking them out ever since.

Answer (score 4):

There's really nothing wrong with the functionality (UX) of round door knobs for most people and from an mechanical engineering standpoint they allow less leverage to be applied to the door.  This allows a less expensive knob assembly and door. All in all, they're less expensive than lever handles.

And lever handles are more likely to injure a child if they fall against them.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with them, actually. Soapy hands, holding groceries, etc.

Comment: @DA01, people with severe arthritis...

Comment: See this: http://www.japantoday.com/images/size/x/2012/05/handles.jpg

Comment: What about hygiene? I prefer not to touch door knobs/handles on toilet doors. With knobs that isn’t even remotely a possibility. You can just use your elbow  for opening a toilet door with a handle (yes, even if it opens to the outside: you put your elbow behind the handle and pull ;) ).

Answer (score 3):

Although ergonomics probably have very little to do with it, doorknobs do have an ergonomic advantage.

A doorknob can be grasped at any angle, whereas a horizontal lever must be grasped palm down (or up, if you prefer) which isn't a natural position. The natural position of the hand is palm inwards, slightly down.

Also, a doorknob is usually pretty spherical, which also happens to be the natural position of the fingers. Levers come in quite a few shapes, most of them designed for style and not for ergonomics. Sometimes an awkward pose of the hand is required to grasp it properly.

That said, levers generally don't require grasping to open, and the differences are pretty unimportant.

Comment: There is also the opposite problem when the knob is (often) too close to the edge of the door and one can't turn the knob or close the door without trapping your thumb in the jamb.  This is very inconvenient and painful.

Comment: @nicodemus13 Wow, I've never experienced that.

Comment: A horizontal lever does not have to be *grasped* at all. It just needs to be pressed, which is possible in any position of the hand, and even with other parts of the body or objects than a hand.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to run a heuristic analysis of buildings, I'd find that most users are familiar with doorknobs, and while they might express a preference for levers, it doesn't factor into their decision to enter a building.

Additionally, I would likely find that mortise locks require a heavier door and cost several times more to purchase/install.

Thus, I would conclude that doorknobs provide an increased ROI on the margin vs. door levers with a minimal impact on engagement, in spite of their their inherent disadvantages.

This wouldn't be the best decision for the user, but it's the sort of compromise we make on a daily basis in business.

Comment: Most users **in America** are familiar with doorknobs - as discussed extensively elsewhere on this page, this is a cultural phenomenon, and the network effect would point in precisely the opposite direction in, say, the UK.

Comment: The way my last landlord explained it, the use of mortise configurations in the UK has to do with the age of the architecture. Old doors won't take modern deadbolts in a secure way, and as a result you have your own default setup. This came up because mortise locks were a trend in San Francisco during the 1990s. As a result, in many commercial spaces, we're now stuck with a configuration requirement that costs $2000 to replace instead of $400.

Answer (score 0):

This is anecdotal, but:

In the building in which I currently live, we used to have several doors with lever-style handles. They were actually removed and replaced with doorknobs, because people kept putting too much pressure on the levers and *breaking* the mechanisms.

From this I infer that levers might not be a good choice for very high-traffic doors. A broken mechanism is the least usable one of all - and obviously the expense plays a part as well, for whomever has to pay to replace it.

Although it doesn't seem very practical for inside houses/apartments, many office and condo/apartment buildings use "panic bars" and sometimes thumbpiece mechanisms instead, for highly-trafficked doors; less frustrating than doorknobs, but still difficult to break accidentally. So it's not entirely a competition between doorknobs and levers - there are other options available.

Comment: What!? That must have been some seriously cheap mechanisms if they break from people using just using their hands, unless it was vandalism and people were kicking the handles or smashing them with hammers. All doors with handles I've ever used can handle slamming your hand on it so hard your hand hurts just fine.

Comment: A really high traffic door (such as the front door of a office building/shop) should not have a latching mechanism anyway. They would typically be automatic or self closing with a push pad on one side and a static pull handle on the other.