# Why are jail bars vertical and not horizontal?

Tags: design

One reason could be that they are better fixed in ground than in walls. Was this the only reason?

Comment: I am a bit curious about what prompted you to ask this question. I guess you are only talking about the context of imprisonment and not the use of bars for household security purposes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the history of imprisonment. I fail to see the User Experience aspect of jail bar alignment.

Comment: @BennySkogberg aren't many UX.SE questions of the form `why does something is the way it is?` What's so different then about my question?

Comment: @MichaelLai `bars for household security`? I don't get what you mean by that.

Comment: Other questions are at least related to UX, usch as http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52336/why-is-the-mouse-cursor-slightly-tilted-and-not-straight. But I can't see that on Jail Bars, I'm afraid.

Comment: @BennySkogberg there was a coffee maker question here IIRC. Could you point me to a link where it defines what is meant by UX for this forum?

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @user13107 Bars can also be fixed to window frames to prevent home intruders from getting access to the house through the windows.

Comment: Are they? Using google images I can find a ton of images of prisons where the bars are in horizontal orientation, and/or where they bars are a combination of horizontal and vertical bars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Floors and ceilings are stronger than walls
2. One can climb horizontal bars as one would a ladder
3. One can use the body's strongest muscles to apply force to the bars

Regarding @SNag's quote from Quora- Namit Kothari must not be a welder. Usually in steel the weld is the strongest part of the structure.

I'll give you one more reason that hasn't been mentioned - it's easier to put a door into a vertical bar setup, since the vertical bars wouldn't require an additional frame to support the door.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of user experience, so...

- This is a wild guess, but if they were horizontal, prisoners can use the added support of gravity to bend them.
- They fit better in the ground.
- Usually the distance from ground to ceiling is shorter than the distance between side walls. More the distance, easier it is to bend a bar.
- Prisoners can use horizontal bars to hang themselves.
- Horizontal bars are easy to climb.
- If you have horizontal bars, you need a column in the middle to attach a door, if not the door is one of those weird cat-flap things.

Comment: Can't vertical bars also be used to hang themselves? It is just how you tie the knot.

Comment: @MichaelLai: But knots will often slide down in vertical bars. Not all of the prisoners were boy-scouts.

Answer (score 1):

This question was recently asked and answered on `Quora`. For the benefit of the non-Quora user, I reproduce the top answers and comments here:

> I believe the answer lies in Newton's third law of motion. The bars
>   are made thick to prevent a prisoner to break out free.
>
> Case 1 : Assume the bars are horizontal. In this case, the prisoner
>   has a better chance to bend the bars as the ground gives the desired
>   'normal reaction' to the prisoner against the force applied by the
>   prisoner to bend the bars. This makes it easy to achieve the result.
>
> Case 2 : Assume the bars are vertical. The force required by the arms
>   (way weaker than thighs) is same but the arms require better leverage
>   than thighs to bend the bars which makes it way more difficult to
>   break free.

(Source: [Namit Kothari's answer to Why are jail bars vertical and not horizontal?](http://www.quora.com/Why-are-jail-bars-vertical-and-not-horizontal/answer/Namit-Kothari))

> There are two reasons for this - strength and cost - both of which are
>   related to the welding.
>
> The weakest point of a metal structure is the weld holding it
>   together. A vertical door (ie one longer in height than width) will
>   have less individual bars (and less weak points) than a horizonal one
>   if the bars are the same thickness. Therefore it is a stronger door,
>   which is its main purpose.
>
> The other factor is that a weld must be applied by a welder, which
>   takes time and effort. Less welds equal less time, which is generally
>   cheaper.

(Source: [Tom LeGrice's comment on Namit Kothari's answer](http://www.quora.com/Why-are-jail-bars-vertical-and-not-horizontal/answer/Namit-Kothari/comment/5336395))

> ...there might also be a psychological or affordance-based reason,
>   namely that the horizontal bars would allow the prisoner to look from
>   side to side over the horizon and have sense of "free range" from
>   that. The vertical bars will obstruct this visual sense of freedom and
>   "clip" the visual space into smaller bits. I am guessing that could be
>   an "effect" subconsciously wanted by the imprisoner.

(Source: [Martin Kofod Ludvigsen's answer to Why are jail bars vertical and not horizontal?](http://www.quora.com/Why-are-jail-bars-vertical-and-not-horizontal/answer/Namit-Kothari))

See all answers here [QUORA: Why are jail bars vertical and not horizontal?](http://www.quora.com/Why-are-jail-bars-vertical-and-not-horizontal)

Comment: problems with these reasons is that without references, they could be thought of afterwards rather than before design.

Comment: @user13107: I agree, but sometimes it's hard to find references for these kind of questions and most reasoning seems retrospective. Check [this similar question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57929/why-do-door-knobs-still-exist).